# Including syntax in SAS ODS pdf file

Tags: sas, sas-ods

Is it possible to include submitted syntax or even output of log file when ODS into a PDF using SAS?

For instance, give this simple code:

```
ods pdf file = "c:\temp\myPDF.pdf";
proc reg data = mydata;
model y = x;
run;
ods pdf close;
```

I can get the regression output and accompanying graph fine. But is it possible to incorporate into PDF the enclosed command like this?

```
proc reg data = mydata;
model y = x;
run;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is, but it requires a couple of hoops.  Luckily, you could wrap this into macros to clean up your code.

1. Create a temporary `fileref` to hold your log.
2. Start your PDF and output the log to the fileref.
3. Write code.
4. Stop writing log to fileref.
5. Print file contents to PDF using `ODF TEXT=`

Hope this helps

```
filename x temp;

ods pdf file="c:\temp\temp.pdf";
title "Cost of Power";
options source;
proc printto log=x;
run;

proc reg data=sashelp.cars;
model msrp = horsepower;
run;
quit;

proc printto;run;

title;
ods pdf startpage=now; /*Force a new page in the PDF*/

data _null_;
infile x;
input;
call execute("ods text='LOG: "||_infile_||"';");
run;

ods pdf close;

filename x ;
```